# Does anyone know of a plugin to do dynamic calculations in the django formset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Does anyone know if there is a jquery plug-in that can do calculations for a django formset (it is a dynamic form, it changes the id of each field per row each time the add button is clicked)

Comment: https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset

Comment: mmm but that is more to do the formset not to do dynamic calculations in JS

Comment: correct, it makes it easy to add/delete forms in a formset dynamically using javascript by changing the ids and number of TOTAL_FORMS, perhaps describe what kind of calculations you need to perform... are you doing math with fields in each form of your formset?

Comment: if they are dynamic inputs that multiply and take percentages. I will review the plugin that you indicate because I did not know that calculations could also be easily made

Comment: github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset does not do math calculations on form fields

Answer (score 1):

The returned datetime must be timezone-aware or the plugin will be ignored (with a warning) during expiration calculations. int. An number of seconds that this [site](https://massic.org/give/) ...

Comment: thank you very much, i will put it into practice